# Android permissions required for Firebase authentication

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am currently working on a android application and i have a doubt. I am using firebase for authentication, so do i have to provide any more user permission other than internet to my application?

Comment: In the future, please try to write a title that summarizes your problem.  "I just have a query regarding android application" describes hundreds of thousands of questions on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're asking about permissions to add to the Android manifest, no, there is nothing to add manually.  Each Firebase SDK will automatically add the permissions it requires.